# How to handle angular routes in express, getting: "res.sendFile is not a function"

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have an angular app being served from a node server as static files.
Everything works fine if I start on http://localhost:3000, all the angular routes work.
But if I put direct an address with an angular route in it (for example: http://localhost:3000/login) or if I refresh a page, I get the error: "TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function".

I already search here in stack overflow, but I couldn't find a solid answer to solve this.

This is the routes section of the app.js:

```js
app.use("/api", commonRoutes);
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);

// This returns the static file, but only for http://localhost:3000
app.use((res, req, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "angular", "index.html"));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have `app.use((res, req, next)` arguments in incorrect order. Try

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "angular", "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: Such a simple thing, I can't believe it  Thanks a lot Tom!!